# Simple math addition in array indicies?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am trying to edit the values in an array index.  I wrote a while loop & iterate over 10 times and add the iterator to the array index value.

```
var values = [[100,0],[0,100],[3,400]];

i=0;
while(i<10){
    values[0][0]+=i;
    values[0][1]+=i;
    i++;
}

values[0][1]; //this returns 45 ???
```

However values[0][1] returns 45??? I didn't expect to get 45 from that addition? I can't figure out how to correctly add values to array indexes.

Comment: not sure what you want to archieve, but 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45, nothing wrong with that

Comment: In your loop: `values[0][1]+=i;` sets `values[0][1]` to `0` the first time, then adds 1, then adds **2**, then adds **3** all the way up to **9**. 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45

Comment: You should probably add what you *were* expecting, so that we know what you're trying to accomplish with the code.

Comment: You could try a technique called "walking through the code". You pretend you're the computer, and go line by line.You can keep track of variable values on a piece of paper. When you do this, you'll see that the code does exactly what it should. I don't understand what you mean by "add values to array indexes" You're not adding values to the indexes, you're adding values to the values in the array.

Comment: Or use a debugger and step through the code so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I am not so clever because I was expecting the array index to be added by 10 because the while loops 10 times. But I can see how messed up. Thanks for these insights @CullenJ

Comment: @Felice No problem, I know how it feels to be staring at a simple line of code that "should work" and not see the one little mistake that is throwing everything off.